# Python: Rotation Matrix to Angles

Tags: python, math, matrix, geometry

Given a rotation matrix

```
     | r00  r01  r02 |
 R = | r10  r11  r12 |
     | r20  r21  r22 |
```

and an specific rotation sequence 'abc' where a, b, c are taken from 'XYZ'.
Is there a **general solution** (for an arbitrary rotation sequence) available in Python to translate the rotation matrix into rotation angles around X, Y, and Z axis?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "specific rotation sequence 'abc' where a, b, c are taken from 'XYZ'". Your question seems complete without that phrase and the phrase is unclear.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50963/how-to-extract-euler-angles-from-transformation-matrix

Comment: This is a common problem in robotics and 3D graphics I believe. Check out "Roll, Pitch, Yaw", and [this university page](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node103.html) on determining them.

Comment: see [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems every rotation sequence has its separate solution. Given a
sequence "ZYX" the resulting symbolic expression for the rotation 
matrix is

```
       |      Cy Cz              -Cy Sz             Sy  |
Rxyz = │  Sx Sy Cz + Cx Sz   -Sx Sy Sz + Cx Cz   -Sx Cy │
       | -Cx Sy Cz + Sx Sz    Cx Sy Sz + Sx Cz    Cx Cy |
```

with `C` and `S` for cosine and sine. `x`, `y`, `z` indices note
the rotation around x, y, and z axis. From that, a set of equations
may be derived, namely:

```
           Cy Cz = r00
         - Cy Sz = r01
         - Sx Cy = r02
Sx Sy Cz + Cx Sz = r10
      ...
```

Those need to be resolved for at least one angle expression for 
each axis. Then, 'arcsin' or 'arccos' is applied to get the real
angle. It seems that the symbolic math needs to be performed for
each sequence separately.